# Издательская система LaTeX

Tags: latex

Расскажите, пожалуйста, об издательской системе LaTeX, о её преимуществах и недостатках, именно по вашему мнению (кратко)?

Comment: Зачем? Уже всё сто раз рассказано и показано. Если вам простые документы подготавливать, то может быть даже не стоит и смотреть в эту сторону. По большому счёту от TeX используются сейчас таблицы переносов (слов) и рендерер математических формул. Всё остальное вытеснил ужасный MS Office.

Comment: TeX - компилятор. Я писал проги на СРР для формирования кода ТеХ (таблицы с подстановкой вычисленных функций). По ним же можно рисовать по-верху. Отличная система! Но не WYSIWYG